# T-SQL: Filtering columns by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to generate columns based on the date of the activity.
I used `FULL JOIN` before but it only generated duplicated rows even when using `CASE`.

Some guidance on how to approach this would be great.
`Table 1` is my current data and `Result` is the table I am looking for.

[image]

Comment: You should provide an example of the SQL you tried.

Comment: please DON'T insert pictures. people prefer text, to have test data.

Comment: Test data: http://rextester.com/GYYU12454

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PIVOT() on dynamic sql to allow the unknown number of dates in the [date] column to be used as column names after transposition.

Since you cannot directly PIVOT the raw data by having MAX(activity) which will give only one row each userid, you can have an inner sub-query that will introduce another column, rnum from ROW_NUMBER(). This will not allow the aggregation in userid level and maintain the number of rows.

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME([date]) 
                     FROM table1 t -- use your table name
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                  ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT userid, ' + @cols + '
                FROM (SELECT userid, rnum, ' + @cols + '
                        FROM (SELECT *,
                                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid, 
                                                                     [date] 
                                                            ORDER BY [date]) rnum
                                FROM table1) x
                        PIVOT (MAX(activity)
                          FOR [date] IN (' + @cols +')) p
                      ) t
               ORDER BY userid'

EXECUTE(@query)
GO
```

Result

```
userid  2018-09-10  2018-09-11  2018-09-12
1       gym         run         gym
1       run         NULL        run
1       push-ups    NULL        NULL
2       gym         NULL        gym
3       run         NULL        run
4       gym         push-ups    gym
4       NULL        run         NULL
```

Comment: If I were to limit the dates to between 09-10 and 09-11, how would I change @cols? Because eventually, I would like to pass a variable in which I can define the range of dates to get only a specific week.

Comment: you may include a WHERE clause inside the query for SET @cols before FOR XML PATH() like this WHERE [date] BETWEEN CAST('2018-09-10' AS DATE) AND CAST('2018-09-11' AS DATE)

Comment: Perfect, couldn't be better than that!

Comment: If I need to restrict the table1 and have only users 1 and 2, I wouldn't be able to replace table1 for another select statement under @query. I tried using a table variable but got some errors in reference to its declaration. How would I be able to do that?

Comment: you mean, you wanted to filter it by userid -- WHERE userid IN (1,2)?

Comment: Not exactly, but I ended up finding a solution in which I just replaced "table1"  from here:   "FROM table1) x"     with a VIEW that I created based on the restrictions that I have.

Comment: I see. Great! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userid, date, activity
FROM table1
WHERE date = '9/10/2018'
UNION ALL
SELECT userid, date, activity
FROM table1
WHERE date = '9/11/2018'
UNION ALL
SELECT userid, date, activity
FROM table1
WHERE date = '9/12/2018';
```

Comment: Would be improved with some explanation.

Comment: Your output doesn't match the results required : http://rextester.com/RCCLJM11364